# JMS Serializer Deserialization With Multiple Types

Tags: php, jms-serializer

Often when consuming an api, a response will contain json that can be an array or a string (or two different types).  I've been struggling to find a way to get JMS Serializer to handle these cases.

I've found that I can set `@SerializedName` on two different properties to handle serialization (as long as you're not serializing nulls and only one is set).  However, this breaks on deserialization.

Comment: how did you fix this?